# Движение UI за GameObject

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

Есть ли какой то элегантный способ перемещать ui панель за объектом на сцене при условии что рендер мод канваса == Screen space - Overlay?

Я пока что делаю так:

```
private void Update()
{
   rect.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(target.transform.position) + new Vector(0, 3, 0);
}
```

Где rect это RectTransform. Но кажется мне это костыль в апдейте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут самое странное это каждый раз искать `main` камеру и обращаться к `transform` у `GameObject` который не используется.

Ты пользуешься `RectTransform` как обычным `Transform`, при сложной иерархии `position` в `ui` косячет. `ScreenPoint` это координата на дисплее, а не на `Canvas`, в твоем случае размер соответствует, на устройстве все легко подйдет нахер. Если объект будет дочерним тому, который не растянут до краев сломается сразу.

Кроме того `new Vector(0, 3, 0)`, магическое число, значение которого нельзя изменить и почему оно такое знает только автор, не вынесенное как константа или поле. Тут ясно что это `offset`, не понятно только почему сдвиг не внутри скобок, а еще непонятней почему просто указать не сам объект как `target`, а пустой `GameObject` внутри него который выполняет функцию маркера позиции для `ui` и редактируется прямо в редакторе, причем для каждого типа персонажа под его рост. Вписывать `offset` как поле и уж темболее хардкодить как ты, вот уж где костыльные костыли.

```
public class UIFollowTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    private RectTransform _transform;
    private RectTransform _parent;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _target;
    
    private void Start ()
    {
        _transform = transform as RectTransform;
        _parent = transform.parent as RectTransform;
    }

    public void SetTarget (Transform target)
    {
        _target = target;
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        Vector3 screenPoint = _camera.WorldToScreenPoint(_target.position);
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(_parent, screenPoint, null, out Vector2 point);
        _transform.anchoredPosition = point;
    }
}
```

Comment: Атрибут `camera` для `Canvas - Screen Overlay` должен быть `null`. В остальных случаях указывается. Читаем документацию [ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle.html).